# How to make a button change an object on a different page C# Metro app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

Basically my app is an app with lessons, and the lessons are seperated into different pages.

The easiest way for me to describe is this.

Menu with:

Lesson 1

Lesson 2

Lesson 3

Each lesson page has a button that goes to the next lesson, so if the user is on lesson 1 the next button will navigate straight to lesson 2 and so on. I want the button to change the properties on the button that navigates to lesson 1.

I understand how to change the properties of an object in C#, but I don't know how to call the button from a different page.

If anyone can help it would be a big help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd rethink your approach here (though I'm still a bit unclear of "want the button to change the properties on the button" means).  In general move whatever setup you need into your ViewModel and let the subsequent page just naturally get what it needs.  You can pass data in too via the Navigate call, but having hard-coded dependencies between pages is 1) difficult to implement and 2) will cause you pain in the long run.

Comment: Try reading some information about using MVVM in Windows 8 apps. There's an excellent article by Laurent Bugnion over here on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx

Comment: you can use messenger class for this..it is avialable in mvvm light for windows 8